# Relative links to admin.py

Tags: django

There is a class in admin.py:

```
class NewsAdmin(TranslationAdmin):
    form = NewsForm
    list_display = ('title', 'date' 'show_url')
    
    def show_url(self, obj):
        return format_html("<a href='http://www.host.ru/news/{url}' target='_blank'>view</a>", url=obj.id)
        
    show_url.short_description = "View"
```

Need a link http://www.host.ru replace with a relative one, something like this: protocol + domain name + news/{url}
How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are better off making it hardcoded value in your settings, like `BASEURL = 'http://www.host.ru'`
then having different settings.py for production and development (dev with `BASEURL = 'https://localhost:8080'` for testing)

and then you can fetch it with:

```py
def show_url(self, obj):
    from django.conf import settings
    return format_html("<a href='{base}/news/{url}' target='_blank'>view</a>", base=settings.BASEURL, url=obj.id)

# or use reverse so it's dynamically linked to your urls.py (this is what I do)
def show_url_with_reverse(self, obj):
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.urls import reverse
    return format_html("<a href='{base}{url}' target='_blank'>view</a>",
        base=settings.BASEURL,
        url=reverse('myviewname', args=[obj.id])
        )
```

This isn't the answer you wanted, but I'm throwing it in as a way. I hope someone smarter than me has found a better way, but this is a fallback.

---

#### Reasoning

**This is all moot** because you don't have access to the `request` object inside that method.
I've found that you need the `request` object to dynamically get the host, the **[www.host.ru](http://www.host.ru)** part, with `request.get_host()`.
But that still leads the `http://` and `https://`, which is not available **anywhere** *(that I've found)*, so I have that hardcoded in my settings.py.

So either way **something** will have have to be hardcoded, so might as well be the entire url. It's gross, I hate it, but w/e it gets the job done

Comment: Thank you so much!
I think I will have to finalize this decision, but this is what I need.